# Extract user names from Users list with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have the following method where I use RxJava to get some data from Api and then I  manipulate that data to get list of user names and list of users.

```
public void getUsers(){
disposables = RxUtil.initDisposables(disposables);

Disposable disposable = userApiRepository.getUsers()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .doOnNext(otherUsers -> {
      List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
      for(OtherUser otherUser: otherUsers){
        names.add(otherUser.getDisplayName());
      }

      String[] userNames = names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
      view.onUserNamesLoaded(userNames);
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(otherUsers -> view.onUsersLoaded(otherUsers),
               view::handleError);

disposables.add(disposable);
}
```

I do not like this approach in **doOnNext**, since I think that it could be improved, but not sure how.

Can someone write a better solution?

Comment: Yes - move it into your `subscribe()` block

Comment: But still it would be the same code without almost any change.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to improve in that case, as aside from using `doOnNext` instead of `subscribe()` your our code looks fine. You could use stream instead , `view.onUserNamesLoaded(otherUsers.stream().map(OtherUser::getDisplayName).toArray(String[]::new))`, but it's debatable whether or not that's any clearer

Comment: you can use map operator

Comment: That code should be in `subscribe`, and if this `for...` stuff bothers you, start using Kotlin which gives you the Kotlin Collections API.

Answer (score 1):

```
    userApiRepository
    .getUsers()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMapIterable(users -> users)
    .map(OtherUser::getDisplayName)
    .toList()
    .doOnNext(names -> view.onUserNamesLoaded(names.toArray(new String[names.size()])))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(otherUsers -> view.onUsersLoaded(otherUsers),
               view::handleError);
```

Edit: this doesn't do what the original snipped did; I believe the following does:

```
userApiRepository
    .getUsers()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(otherUsers -> updateViewWithUserNames(otherUsers, view))
    .subscribe(otherUsers -> view.onUsersLoaded(otherUsers),
               view::handleError);

private void updateViewWithUserNames(List<OtherUsers> otherUsers, View view) {
    view.onUserNamesLoaded(otherUsers.stream()
                                     .map(OtherUser::getDisplayName)
                                     .toArray(String[]::new));
}
```

Comment: While this might be correct, I'm not sure if it really is an improvement. (Also, the views are manipulated from schedulers.io(), I wonder why the original question's code worked).

Comment: Would this work? Wouldn't `otherUsers` in `subscribe` now be a list of Strings, rather than a list of `OtherUser`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yup, the view change should be after the `observeOn`. Other than that, it's (IMHO) subjective.

Comment: @PPartisan Hmmm... I think you're right; in that case it should probably be moved to a separate method. Edited the reply.